# composite C1 form Renderer localization

Tags: localization, c1-cms

I have created a global data type, and use form renderer in a page to let user fill in the data and submit to website.

The default English is working fine.
now when I try to support the second language I run into issues.  According to the composite documentation:

1.Add your empty localization file at ~/Frontend/CompositeForms/Renderer/Localization/, for example: Composite.FormsRenderer.de-de.xml
2.Copy the contents of the default Composite.FormsRenderer.en-us.xml to your localization file.
3.Translate the strings.
4.In ~/App_Data/Composite/Composite.config, under the section  locate Composite.Plugins.FormsRenderer's add section and register your localization file

but ~/Frontend/CompositeForms/Renderer/Localization does not exist, and neither  does Composite.FormsRendereren-us.xml exists.

is the documentation outdated? does anyone had experience with localizing form renderer on user defined data type?

thanks

Comment: remember to include what version of C1 you're running. Configuration of Localization in composite.config has changed dramatically lately and this could be what you're experiencing.

Comment: I am using composite c1 4.0.4837, it's beta version downloaded from codeplex and compiled locally.  form renderer package is install from console->System->available package.

Comment: yes, then the documentation is not up to date, its written for 3.2.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation IS outdated at the moment (and will be updated soon - thanks for pointing it out).

Do it in the following way on 4.0 or later:

1. Make a copy of ~/Composite/InstalledPackages/localization/Composite.Forms.Renderer.en-us.xml, changing the language/culture code from 'en-us' to your language's (e.g. Composite.Forms.Renderer.de-de.xml).
2. Translate the strings.

No need to change anything in ~/App_Data/Composite/Composite.config any more.